# How to get Assignment Approvals Items using CSOM?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

Currently i am developing an application to access my company Sharepoint Site in more simple ways. One of my application features is to access Approvals Item (or in my research define as _moderationStatus).

I have done a lot of research to get this thing done but what i've found was to get Approvals (_moderationStatus) from List. Meanwhile what i really need is to get Approvals from Assignments / Tasks. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Here the code i've found that have closest relation to what i want (i think)

```
this.oListItemUpdate = oList.getItemById(listID);

var wrkFlwApproval = this.oListItem.get_item(‘_ModerationStatus’);
if(wrkFlwApproval == 0)
{
  this.oListItemUpdate.set_item(‘_ModerationStatus’, 0 );    
}

public enum SPModerationStatusType
{
  Approved, //0
  Denied,   //1
  Pending,  //2
  Draft,    //3
  Scheduled //4
}
```

If i can get the TaskList in sharepoint List i can use that code, but i can't find them. If there any other solution it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSOM code for your reference.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp2013");
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
ctx.Load(listItems);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var listItem in listItems)
{
    string status = "";
    string mStatus = listItem["_ModerationStatus"].ToString();
    if (mStatus == "0")
    {
        status = "Approved";
    }
    else if (mStatus == "1")
    {
        status = "Denied";
    }
    else if (mStatus == "2")
    {
        status = "Pending";
    }
    else if (mStatus == "3")
    {
        status = "Draft";
    }
    else if (mStatus == "4")
    {
        status = "Scheduled";
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + listItem["Title"] + " Approval Status:" + status);
}
```

Comment: When i was tried this solution it shows Error message "List 'Tasks' does not exist at site with URL (my site)"

Comment: The "Tasks" is my test task list, you need change it to your list name.

Comment: I've found that in my site Tasks List is inside Project Site. I'm ok with that but ["_ModerationStatus"] return "0" or Approved in all available task meanwhile in Approvals it has pending Tasks